# How to move zeros to the bottom of a matrix in pascal?

Tags: arrays, matrix, pascal

I have a matrix for ex.:

```
xy 1 2 3 4 5
-------------
1| 1 1 1 2 3
2| 3 0 2 0 0
3| 2 2 1 3 0
4| 3 1 3 2 3
5| 1 0 0 1 0
6| 0 2 1 3 1
-------------
```

and I want  to push all the zeros to the bottom of each column, like this:

```
xy 1 2 3 4 5
-------------
1| 1 1 1 2 3
2| 3 2 2 3 3
3| 2 1 1 2 1
4| 3 2 3 1 0
5| 1 0 1 3 0
6| 0 0 0 0 0
-------------
```

I made this procedure but doesn't work properly, sometimes it works on some columns but leaves zeros in the middle on others

```
procedure MoveZeros(var matnum:matriz);
var x,y,aux:integer;
begin

    for y:= min to maxcol do begin

        for x:= min to maxfil do begin

            if (matnum[x,y] = 0) then begin 
                
                matnum[x,y] := matnum[x+1,y];
                matnum[x+1,y]:=0;

            end;
                
        end;
    end;

end;
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach will work if you never see more than one 0 at a time - if you do then only the last in the sequence will be moved down.

The trick here is to use a separate pointer that holds the position the highest unfilled zero that we've seen. Then, when we see a non-zero value we move it to this position and increment the pointer. Once we reach the bottom of the column, if this pointer isn't at the end then we write in a 0 and increment the pointer until it is.

Hopefully it won't be too difficult to convert this simple Java code to Pascal

```java
int[][] a = {{1, 1, 1, 2, 3},
             {3, 0, 2, 0, 0},
             {2, 2, 1, 3, 0},
             {3, 1, 3, 2, 3},
             {1, 0, 0, 1, 0},
             {0, 2, 1, 3, 1},       
            };


for(int y=0; y<a[0].length; y++)
{
    int z = 0;
    for(int x=0; x<a.length; x++)
    {
        if(a[x][y] != 0)
        {
            if(z < x) 
                a[z][y] = a[x][y];
            z += 1;
        }               
    }
    for(; z<a.length; z++)          
        a[z][y] = 0;
}

for(int[] row : a)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 2, 3, 3]
[2, 1, 1, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 3, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 3, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: thanks, althoug the code didn't work on my environment the description you provided helped figure out the problen and come up with a solution, simple as adding another for with an incremental counter to push all the remaining zeroes to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

For each column examine each element and make a list of the non-zero elements. Then rewrite the column with the non-zero elements in order and write zero to the remaining positions.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually wanna “push” the zeros down, or rather “pull”, then you’ll need to run up and down in one column. This look like that (Extended Pascal, ISO 10206):

```pascal
procedure pullZerosDown(var matrix: array[
        columnMinimum..columnMaximum: integer;
        rowMinimum..rowMaximum: integer
    ] of integer);
var
    x: type of columnMinimum;
    y: type of rowMinimum;
begin
    for x := columnMinimum to columnMaximum do
    begin
        y := rowMaximum;
        while y > rowMinimum do
        begin
            if matrix[x, y] = 0 then
            begin
                for y := y to rowMaximum - 1 do
                begin
                    matrix[x, y] := matrix[x, y + 1];
                    matrix[x, y + 1] := 0;
                end;
                
                repeat
                begin
                    y := y - 1;
                end
                until matrix[x, y] <> 0;
            end
            else
            begin
                y := y - 1;
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

It’s definitely less efficient, but it works. You don’t need an extra “pointer” variable like @RaffleBuffle suggested. This piece of code demonstrates, that you can *implicitly* store information simply by *where* you are, where your PC (program counter) is.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to move the zeroes to the bottom of the column, so:

```
Type Matrix = Array [RowMin..RowMax, ColMin..ColMax] of integer;
procedure MoveZeros(var matnum:matriz);
var x,y,Bottom:integer;
begin
    for y:= colmin to colmax do 
    begin
       Bottom := RowMax;
       while (Matnum[Bottom,y] = 0) and (Bottom > RowMin) do {Find last non-zero}
           Bottom := Pred(Bottom); {or Dec(Bottom); or Bottom := Bottom-1; }
       X := Rowmin;
       repeat
           if (matnum[x,y] = 0) then 
            begin  {interchange}
                matnum[x,y] := matnum[bottom,y];
                matnum[bottom,y]:=0;
                Bottom  := Pred(Bottom); { reduce search size }
            end;                
            X := Succ(X); {Move down the list}
       until X>Bottom;
    end;
end;
```

The nice thing is, as it moves zeros down, it excludes entries that we *know* are zero. So it potentially becomes faster as it goes along.